# Integrate $ \int \frac{4x^2+2x}{(3x-1)(x^2+1)}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions, integration-by-parts

> $$ \int \frac{4x^2+2x}{(3x-1)(x^2+1)}dx$$

I am having difficulty determining which integration technique to use for the above question. I have tried partial fraction decomposition with two different approaches but fail to get the correct answer. I also attempted integration by parts but was unable to get to a place where I could integrate.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to which integration technique would work best for solving this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: For future reference, it would be beneficial to post your attempts, so others can proofread it or avoid telling you something you already know. You can type up your posts after looking over [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Partial fraction should be the way to go. Maybe you made some small mistakes somewhere along the line. You could try showing us the work you've done so far so we can locate the mistakes.

Comment: d what???????????

Answer (score 3):

Noting that the partial fractions method is indeed the way to go, we set up the problem first by trying to find the partial fractions:

$\dfrac{4x^2+2x}{(3x-1)(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{A}{3x-1}+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$

I will let you do the intermediary steps, but the partial fractions comes out to be $A=1; B=1; C=1$

$\int \frac{x+1}{x^2+1}dx$ seems tricky but divide this integral into $\int\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx+\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Comment: Thank you for the help! Turns out I had everything correct, I just did not do ∫x+1x2+1dx∫x+1x2+1dx seems tricky but divide this integral into ∫xx2+1dx+∫1x2+1dx. I probably just need to remember this rule, but why is this legal?

Comment: $\int_a^b f(x)+g(x)dx=\int_a^bf(x) dx+\int_a^bg(x)dx$ and $\frac{x+1}{x^2+1}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: partial fraction decomposition yields
$$
\frac{4x^{2}+2x}{(3x-1)(x^{2}+1)}=\frac{x+1}{x^{2}+1}+\frac{1}{3x-1}.
$$
You can check your answer using the following:
$$
\int\frac{x+1}{x^{2}+1}=\frac{1}{2}\log(x^{2}+1)+\tan^{-1}(x)+C_{1}\text{ and }\int\frac{1}{3x-1}=\frac{1}{3}\log(3x-1)+C_{2}.
$$

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{3x-1}=\frac13ln|(3x-1)|+C_2$